# Spring Cloud Security Resource Server and JSON Vulnerability Protection

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-security

According to [JSON Vulnerability Protection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#json-vulnerability-protection) I prefix JSON responses:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setJsonPrefix(")]}',\n");
    return converter;
}
```

It works fine with AngularJS, but not with `@EnableOAuth2Resource`-App, because Jackson can't parse response from Authorization Server. Firthermore, I can't override

```
    @Bean
    public TokenStore jwtTokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer());
    }
```

definition from `org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.JwtTokenServicesConfiguration` to configure ObjectMapper/RestTemplate because of autoconfiguration ordering and [SPR-13980](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13980).

Maybe I'm missing a solution?

Comment: Don't use the auto configuration, copy and override what you need.